# How to find out what columns in a data frame have all unique values or not

Tags: r, function, loops

I am using RStudio. I am trying to form a function that allows me to check if any columns in my data frame have duplicates or not. I would like this function to go through each column and output a TRUE or FALSE. So far I have:

length(unique(electionresults$Obama))==dim(electionresults)[1]

And this works on a single column. How do I get it so I can apply this function on every column in my electionsresult data frame? Is it a loop of some kind. I don't know what to put where $Obama and [1] are to do this.

Comment: How about `sapply(electionresults, anyDuplicated)`?

Comment: Using your method - you can use `apply`, or `sapply`, or `lapply`, or `for` loop... Because you want to do it to *every* column you don't put the name of any one column anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can do

```
setDT(df)
nrow(df) - df[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]
```

This gives the number of duplicate values for each column.

edit: MrFlick's solution `sapply(electionresults, anyDuplicated)` is cleaner and seems to also be about 4x faster.